# International billing solution

Tags: library, invoicing

I'm currently working on the development of a rental vacation website for our company own properties.

I'm looking for a 3rd party solution or an open source software that I can integrate into the website I'm programming now, that will generate invoices (bills) so I can send them to the client when he books a vacation with us.

Knowing that there are precise rules to follow according to the country where the property is located, could you give me an advice on a solution that works everywhere - or in a specific list of countries according to the law?